# Transition other posts when new post inserted/deleted

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

I have a list of posts rendered with a `#each` block as follows

```
{{#each posts}}
    {{> post}}
{{/each}}
```

When I insert and remove documents from the collection, the DOM is modified likewise, instantly with the other posts snapping into their new position.

Is there any way to take over this reposition with a transition that would let old elements slide out of the way for a new post to fade in, and for lower posts to slide upwards to take the space of a deleted post as it fades out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`_uihooks`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/History.md#blaze-5) to implement transitions when Blaze changes the DOM.
The following hooks are available:

```
var hooks = {
  insertElement: function(node, next) {
    // called when Blaze intends to insert the DOM element node before the element next
  },
  moveElement: function(node, next) {
    // called when Blaze intends to move the DOM element node before the element next
  },
  removeElement: function(node) {
    // called when Blaze intends to remove the DOM element node
  }
}
```

Here are a few examples: [benstr/Meteor_uihooks](https://gist.github.com/benstr/1ed39b35bb0b8e4c5de6), [tmeasday/transition-helper](https://github.com/tmeasday/transition-helper/blob/master/transition-helper.js) and [Meteor JS Animation article provided by Web Tempest](http://www.webtempest.com/meteorjs-animation).

Answer (score 2):

Using _uihooks is a good option for doing animations of data being moved/added/removed from your page. You can also check out the [momentum package](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/momentum)

just run this in your application

```
 meteor add percolate:momentum
```

and then use it in your template within a `{{#with}}` or `{{#each}}` by using the built in helper with one of the plugins `{{#momentum plugin="slide-height"}}`

Comment: Cold you post an Example with {{#each}} ?

Since this is not working for me: 
{{#each products}}
{{#momentum plugin="slide-height"}}
{{> product}}
{{/momentum}}
{{/each}}

Comment: no problem! you just have them inside out is all. `{{#momentum plugin="slide-height"}} {{#each products}} {{> product}} {{/each}} {{/momentum}}`